# Role and Policy Authorization without AspNetCore Identity?

Tags: c#, architecture, authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We are currently moving our internal desktop applications over to a series of Web Apps with a unified [Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/). As such, we are leveraging Identity Server to manage all of our user accounts and allowing it to federate access to our clients and APIs. Overall, this is all working great.

However, I'm not having much luck in finding any examples where someone has managed to implement role or policy-based authorization without utilizing AspNetCore Identity. With IdentityServer managing my users, I would prefer not to have to duplicate my users between my identity server and my individual webapps, and I'd instead prefer to have each webapp manage its own internal permissions.

Are there any examples on how to implement policy-based authorization without leveraging the entirety of AspNetCore Identity?

Comment: as long as your identity object is populated you can leverage the role/policy based authorization

Comment: @Steve I notice that I can use roles that are assigned on the IdentityServer, but how would one go about having app-specific roles that are handled and managed solely on the app itself?

Comment: where are you storing the app-specific roles? is it in the User's object? if not then where is it being stored? Would be easier if you can show your identity object's structure

Comment: @Steve the idea was to store app-specific roles, claims, and policies in the app-specific database. Either by creating a limited `Users` table that merely referenced the `sub` claim from IdentityServer, or by just using the `sub` claim in lieu of a dedicated table.

Comment: @Steve overall, we're wanting the ability to add to the claims/roles a given user is assigned from the identity server. The identity server manages global permissions, but when things get a bit more granular at an application level, we want to add additional claims and roles.

Comment: why not just store the claims in identity server all together? storing them in separate places is just complicating things. There are ways to deal with it but i wouldn't recommend them.

Comment: @Steve We didn't want to make the identity server responsible for knowing the implementation details of the underlying security in the various webapps. This would also require us to implement the our multitenancy piece at the identity server rather than just in the apps that need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is to setup a seperate authentication server and seperate authorization server. As commented [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/#comment-131079) by one of the creators of IdentityServer:

> IdentityServer is both an OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect implementation.
>   Yes – we recommend to use IdentityServer for end-user authentication,
>   federation and API access control.
>
> PolicyServer is our recommendation for user authorization.

The article itself is worth reading, and here's a link to the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) website.

The idea is quite simple, though there are different approaches possible. It's likely that the implementation will take some time because the free, open source version uses a local source, while you will probably want to use a centralized version. In which case you can consider to take a look at the commercial version first.

In short, how it can work. First the user is authenticated. Then the authorization middleware adds the claims to the user. Then the user is authorized. In [code](https://github.com/PolicyServer/PolicyServer.Local/blob/master/src/Host/Startup.cs#L48), something like:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

// add this middleware to make roles and permissions available as claims
// this is mainly useful for using the classic [Authorize(Roles="foo")] and IsInRole functionality
// this is not needed if you use the client library directly or the new policy-based authorization framework in ASP.NET Core
app.UsePolicyServerClaims();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

This will leave the authentication flow intact and 'opt-in' authorization for the user. To speed up performance you can use caching.

The `sub` claim is the key. As part of the oidc flow, that's the one and only claim that remains constant.

The OSS sample works fine for the Mvc client, but when you extend it with a resource (api) it will not work out of the box. Because the access token may not contain all the claims.

And this is the essence, it's the resource that knows best what claims are relevant. So it should be the resource that requests the information.

In fact this is what a local PolicyServer implementation does, a different policy json for the clients and api's. You can move this to a database and use the client/scope as discriminator, defining roles / permissions per user (sub).

The api can use the access token to request information from the authorization server. To solve the problem where the client wants to know which functionality is allowed, e.g. for building menu's, you can extend the authorization server with an endpoint where it can request a list of roles / permissions.